# Navigation bar JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a code to open and close navigation bar with the button
my code is as follows

```
#DIV1{
    display:block;}

        <div id="DIV1">
        <ul class="topnav">
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <button  onClick="abc()">HIDE</button>
    <script>
    function abc()
    {
        var togg = document.getElementById('DIV1')
         if (togg.style.display == "block")
        {
            togg.style.display="none";
        }

        else if (togg.style.display == "none")
        {
            togg.style.display="block";
            }

    }
    </script>
```

It wont work what should I do or what am I doing wrong? There are other CSS properties for navigation bar which I have skipped.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you have to set its display with javascript or with inline style  to get something by yourDiv.style.display. In your case, when you click on your button, the display is not set and then you can't enter nor in your `if` neither in your `else if` statement. So try this:

```js
var togg = document.getElementById('DIV1');
togg.style.display="block"; /* => I set a display value */

function abc(){
   if (togg.style.display == "block")
  {
      togg.style.display="none";
  }

  else if (togg.style.display == "none")
  {
      togg.style.display="block";
  }

}
```

```css
#DIV1 {
   display:block;
}
/*you can remove this rule. You are changing the display via javascript */
```

```html
<div id="DIV1">
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<button  onClick="abc()">HIDE</button>
```

Another way: you could simply create a class to "hide" your div and then toggle it using  `classList` and `toggle`:

```js
function abc(){
    var togg = document.getElementById('DIV1')
    togg.classList.toggle("myClass");
}
```

```css
.myClass {
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV1">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button  onClick="abc()">HIDE</button>
```

Comment: you are awesome <3

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct code:

```html
<style> #DIV1{
    display:block;}
</style>

        <div id="DIV1">
        <ul class="topnav">
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <button  onClick="abc()">HIDE</button>
    <script>
    function abc()
    {
        var togg = document.getElementById('DIV1');
         if (togg.style.display == "block")
        {
            togg.style.display="none";
        }

        else 
        {
           togg.style.display="block";
        }

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Best to provide an explanation of what is different and why it resolves problem

Comment: First click on hide doesn't hide the nav. Second click does.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question try this one:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <style>
     #div1{
        display:block;}
    </style>
            
        <script>
        function abc()
        {
            var togg = document.getElementById("div1")
             if (togg.style.display === "none")// 3 === 
            {
                togg.style.display="block";
            }

            else {
      togg.style.display="none";
            }

        }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="div1">
            <ul class="topnav">
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
              <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>
            <button  onclick="abc()">HIDE</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```